# How to generate a war for a web service created in a console application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I created a web service in Eclipse and it works. I published it in that way:

```
public class MyPublisher{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9900/ws/hi", new MyServiceImpl());
       System.out.println(endpoint.isPublished());

   }
}
```

The fact is that I run it in the console as a "Java application" and not as a "web application".

My application is a normal console application using Maven.

What I want is a WAR that I can deploy on Jboss or any other application server and that run my web service.

How can I do that? How can I generate that from my console application?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is that you are deploying your web-services manually and then testing them via main method.

To deploy in a web-server, you will have to package your Service Endpoint Implementation Classes ( in short, your interface classes along with their implementation classes ) along with required libraries and configurations files as a war file and deploy on your JBoss server.

What you will be needing in a war file are the following basic contents

1. WEB-INF/classes/com/some/package/YourServiceInterface.class
2. WEB-INF/classes/com/mkyong/ws/YourServiceInterfaceImpl.class
3. WEB-INF/web.xml
4. WEB-INF/xml_configuration_files => *This can be services.xml or sux-jaxws.xml or anything depending on what framework you are using.*
5. WEB-INF/lib/library_jars